# Append Data to specific Value in .json-File + cleanup json-Method

Tags: python, json, twitch, voting-system

I just started building my own Twitch Bot with Python. Now I wanted to build an voting funktion. I push the Data into an .json File because I need to access the Data from an Web-Interface to control the Voting (set Questions, activate/de-activate, Playout on the CasparCG-Server) and push it forward to my GC-Server (CasparCG) to show it on my Stream.

```
@bot.command(name="vote")
async def vote(ctx):
    with open("poll.json", "r+") as f:
     data = json.loads(f.read())
     vote_active = (data['poll_active'])
     vote_options = (data['vote_options']['options'])
     print("json File has been read") #Debug
     print("Vote Options:") #Debug
     print(vote_options) #Debug
     print("Vote Active:") #Debug
     print(vote_active) #Debug
     pollOptions = vote_options
     if ctx.author.name not in pollEntrants and vote_active:
        try:
            vote = int(ctx.message.content.split("vote ")[1])
            pollOptions[list(pollOptions.keys())[vote-1]] += 1
            pollEntrants.append(ctx.author.name)
            print ("I did count that!") #Debug
            print(pollEntrants) #Debug
            print(pollOptions) #Debug
        except IndexError:
            pass
     else:
        print ("I didnt't count that!") #Debug
        print(pollEntrants) #Debug
        print(pollOptions) #Debug
        pass
```

And this is my poll.json:

```
{
    "question": "Testquestion",
    "question_desc": "Questiondescription",
    "question_desc_size": "155%",
    "poll_active": true,
    "options": {
        "option1": "Answer 1",
        "option2": "Answer 2",
        "option3": "Answer 3",
        "option4": "Answer 4"
    },
    "vote_options": {
        "options": {
            "opt_1": 0,
            "opt_2": 0,
            "opt_3": 0,
            "opt_4": 0
        }
    }
}
```

So first things first...
the json-File handling is implemented in the voting function. To keep the Function cleaner I tried it with an get_voteopts(): Function.

```
def get_voteopts():
 global vote_options
 global vote_active
with open("poll.json") as f:
     data = json.loads(f.read())
     vote_active = (data['poll_active'])
     vote_options = (data['vote_options']['options'])
     print(vote_options)
```

but calling that function with "get_voteopts()" did nothing. The function gets called once and only gets called again, when I restart the script. This is bad as the json-File only gets checked once and I can't check if the File has been changed externally. But putting this directly in the vote Function does what I want.

**Main Problem and the reason I am looking for help:**

I want to write the collected Data back to the place in the json-File it came from. So I want my Script to update the values in the vote_options, options, opt_1, 2, 3, part of the json-File.

Can someone help me with that Issue? Maybe choosing json was bad in first place.:D If my plans are too complicated, maybe someone can suggest me another file format? XML? YAML?

Regards

Answer (score -1):

Okay. I guess I fixed it myself. But maybe someone knows if there is a cleaner way to do this?

That's what it looks like now.

I open the dictionary (`data`), then I select the exact key, and then I use the `.update` function to update them.

```
@bot.command(name="vote")
async def vote(ctx):
    with open("poll.json", "r+") as f:
     data = json.loads(f.read())
     vote_active = (data['poll_active'])
     vote_options = (data['vote_options']['options'])
     print("json Datei read") #Debug
     print("Vote Options:") #Debug
     print(vote_options) #Debug
     print("Vote Active:") #Debug
     print(vote_active) #Debug
     print ("Content of dict")
     print(data)
     
     if ctx.author.name not in pollEntrants and vote_active:
        try:
            vote = int(ctx.message.content.split("vote ")[1])
            if vote is not None or (vote == 0):
               vote_options[list(vote_options.keys())[vote-1]] += 1
               pollEntrants.append(ctx.author.name)
               data['vote_options']['options'].update(vote_options)
               f.seek(0)
               f.write(json.dumps(data, indent=4))
               f.close
               print ("I did count that!") #Debug
               print(pollEntrants) #Debug
               print(vote_options) #Debug
            else:
                pass
        except IndexError:
             pass
     else:
        print ("I didnt't count that!") #Debug
        print(pollEntrants) #Debug
        print(vote_options) #Debug
        pass
```